# Need help making MyBatis work with a terrible database design

Tags: java, database, orm, jsf, mybatis

So i'm working on a project (JSF2, Spring3 Core, MVC, Webflow, MyBatis3, RichFaces, and a legacy Oracle 10g).  The source of all of my trouble's has to do with the design of the database.  The problem is that the majority of the DB tables have changing schema (bad design perhaps?). So I need to be able to support the addition & removal of extra columns.

To accommodate this i've made MyBatis pull data into a custom "universal" domain object which basically just extends a hashmap.  My current issue is updating these hashmap objects.  There should be a way to make it work, but I can seem to get MyBatis to co-operate.  I've tried using HashMap.entrySet() & MyBatis's , but to no avail. eg.

```
UPDATE MYTABLE
SET 
<foreach collection="entries" index="i" item="entry" close=""  open="" separator=", ">
  #{entry.key} = #{entry.value}
</foreach>
WHERE FOO='BAR';
```

I've tried a custom TypeHandler but setParameter() doesn't give me enough access to do what I need. A ResultHandler didn't give me enough access to each individual result, so I couldn't use that either.

Now I know i could do something like Obj.createUpdateSqlString() and insert it into the mapper as a literal string, but thats a bit of a hack and leaves me open to SQL injection.  Not to mention that would involve escaping a lot of strings, and accounting for a wide range of possible input, and unless all possibilities are covered that opens up the door for some serious bugs.

So is there an established way to do this? Or atleast a halfway decent way? I've heard a number of hardcore MyBatis advocates say they've yet to encounter a situation MyBatis couldn't handle gracefully; so MyBatis experts, please help me out!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like they were trying to avoid using EAV tables.

You have to pick your poison when it comes to dynamically adding fields. EAV is good from a theory standpoint but has serious performance issues on large tables.  While dynamically adding columns is better for query performance you have to deal with a changing table interface and dynamic sql. I wouldn't write the database off as a bad design outright.

You may want to bypass the framework you're using. Query your table schema (for Oracle look at USER_TAB_COLUMNS) and generate the insert/update scripts. Parameterize them so you are safe from injection. It will be a headache but I don't see an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I had been under the impression that variable schema was always a bad thing, but even so there are plenty of other reasons this database has earned it's reputation of being poorly designed.  I suppose I will just have to avoid using the built-in mappers instead of hacking it up.  Parameterizing the queries was my primary concern but after looking at it I think I might be able to utilize MyBatis for that part at least.  Thanks again!

Comment: Generally it should be avoided. If columns are added at runtime that means the end user is designing tables and may violate normalization rules. But if your application "needs" to add fields at runtime you have to do something...  and that something boils down to EAV, place holder columns, or dynamically adding columns.

Comment: one reason the database may have a "reputation of being poorly designed" is because the end-user is the designer. The end user may start adding columns like Phone1, phone2,...phone322. Letting the user design the tables makes them the designer. Your end-user application starts to becomes a developer tool like SQLDeveloper.

Answer (score 3):

MyBatis or Hibernate both stink with crazy database schemeas. I would just use SpringJDBC or similar.

Don't try to make a round peg fit into a square hole, even if it is a really nice round peg.

Comment: I've recently come to the same conclusion, but unfortunately MyBatis was spec'd for this project early on & now we can't change it (or any of the other libraries) for some nonsensical reason.  Don't you just love corporate bureaucracies.

Comment: @Stoney, 'can't change' is usually just a function of cost - if you can actually prove to the right ears that taking all of the costs into account (*all* internal and external dependencies) you would achieve goals at lesser cost you'd be surprised what can change. On the other hand if presently it is really more expensive to change you'll have to ride it out (on the other hand if by bureaucratic you mean you choose not to do it because such cost analysis would put you in a bad spot due to hierarchy, well... then I am not telling you anything new, so ignore the whole comment)

Comment: There is a way to change it, just depends how hard you are willing to fight :)

Comment: That is very true, I should probably start thinking of things in terms of cost more often. Realistically i'm being a bit cynical; we probably could change the libraries provided a sound logical reason to do so.  The problem here is that the people making the decisions don't have any Java experience, which makes explaining the necessity of changing something much more difficult.  Thanks again everyone for all the great comments/insight